# Convert a list of 3-Tuples in to list of list for a matplot stacked bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, tuples, bin-packing

I have a list of 3 tuples to a bin packing problem solution that looks like this:

```py
sorted_sol = [(0, 1, 170), (1, 1, 250), (2, 1, 250), (3, 1, 62), (3, 2, 30), (4, 1, 62), (4, 3, 62), (5, 2, 122), (6, 1, 212)]
```

As an example the first 3-Tuple means from length 0 cut 1 @ 170

I am trying to convert a list of 3-Tuples in to list of list for a matplot stacked bar chart but am struggling with the loop logic.  The result should be.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
bars = list(set([int(i[0]) for i in sorted_sol]))
#loop logic here to end up with data
b1 = [170, 250, 250, 62, 62, 122, 212]
b2 = [0,   0,   0,   30, 62, 122, 0]
b3 = [0,   0,   0,   30, 62, 0,   0]
b4 = [0,   0,   0,   0,  62, 0,   0]
data =[b1, b2, b3, b4]
for c in range(0, 3):
    if c == 0:
        plt.bar(bars, data[c])
    else:
        plt.bar(bars, data[c], bottom=data[c-1])
plt.show()
```

Additionally the bottom property doesn't seem to be working for me, in that it doesn't appear to stack the bars 3 & 4 correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure what the output is supposed to look like given your list of tuples. Can you provide more info on how to correctly process the data.

Comment: See below post from Quang Hoang for output required.  Still looking for loop logic to arrive at `data` from `sorted_sol`

Comment: The rules aren't clear if you included them in your question. You should probably post the loop you came up with and explain why it is deficient. It might make it clearer how you transform the list of tuples into the four `b` lists.

Comment: `for s, (a, b, c) in enumerate(sorted_sol):print("From length " + str(a) + " cut " + str(b) + " @ " + str(c))`
From length 0 cut 1 @ 170
From length 1 cut 1 @ 250
From length 2 cut 1 @ 250
From length 3 cut 1 @ 62
From length 3 cut 2 @ 30
From length 4 cut 1 @ 62
From length 4 cut 3 @ 62
From length 5 cut 2 @ 122
From length 6 cut 1 @ 212

I guess the biggest issue I'm having is the `len(sorted_sol)` is 9 and the `len(b1)` or unique stock lengths is 7 making the loop logic difficult for me. :)

I should also point out that the stock length for the bin packing problem is 250

Comment: Do you need the different "b" variables? Or is going straight to `data` sufficient?

Comment: Why does `b1[5]` equal 122?  There are more non-zero values in your `b` lists than there are in the list of tuples.

Comment: Straight to `data` is what I'm after.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, something like this should work

```
dx = max(x[0] for x in sorted_sol) + 1
predata = []
for x in range(dx):
    col_data = [tup[1:] for tup in sorted_sol if tup[0] == x]
    temp = [n * [y] for n, y in col_data]
    predata.append([i for sublist in temp for i in sublist])

dy = max(len(x) for x in predata)
data = [[i.pop() if i else 0 for i in predata] for _ in range(dy)]
```

Output:

```
[[170, 250, 250, 30, 62, 122, 212],
 [0, 0, 0, 30, 62, 122, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 62, 62, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 62, 0, 0]]
```

---

The reason your plot doesn't work is because `bottom` needs to be the cumulative sum of the data. Try something like:

```
bottom = 7 * [0]
for i in range(4):
    plt.bar(range(7), data[c], bottom=bottom)
    bottom = [sum([a, b]) for a, b in zip(data[c], bottom)]
```

If you use numpy, the addition on the last line can simply be `data[i] + bottom`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, the output of `data` is correct. I'm still digesting the first code block but at first glance do you see a way of not having to define the ranges `dx` and `dy`.  These ranges will likely vary based on user input etc.  Thanks for pointing out that `bottom` requires cumulative sum of the data, makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not following your logic from `sorted_sol` to the list `b1,b2,b3,b4`. It seems strange to me since your `sorted_sol` only has `3` values of `62` but `data` has 5 such values.

Any how, once you get to `data`, you can consider using `pandas` for stacked bar functionality:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data).T
df.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this works in terms of presenting the data.  Looking at these tuples (3, 1, 62), (4, 1, 62), (4, 3, 62) means from length 3 cut 1 at 62, from length 4 cut 1 at 62 and from length 4 cut 3 at 64. The bin packing solution is from PYTHON-MIP https://docs.python-mip.com/en/latest/examples.html "Cutting Stock / One-dimensional Bin Packing Problem".  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

- [sort](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) the list on (index one, index zero) of the tuples
- [group](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) the list by index one of the tuples
- each group will be a `b` list

  - with tuple index 0 being the index in the (new) `b` list

---

Best that I could see but doesn't seem to fit the list-of-tuple and the `b` lists

Comment: Thanks for your help.  `itertools` is something I need to learn more of.